# Getting error when upgrading from Angular 10 to 11

Tags: angular, typescript, upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade from Angular 10 to 11. When I run the following command, I get an error.

> ng update @angular/core@11 @angular/cli@11

```
The installed local Angular CLI version is older than the latest stable version.

Installing a temporary version to perform the update.

Installing packages for tooling via npm.

Installed packages for tooling via npm.

Using package manager: 'npm'

Collecting installed dependencies...

Found 44 dependencies.

Fetching dependency metadata from registry...

                  Package "@angular-devkit/build-angular" has an incompatible peer dependency to 
"typescript" (requires "~4.0.0 || ~4.1.0", would install "4.3.5")

                  Package "@angular/compiler-cli" has an incompatible peer dependency to "typescript" (requires ">=4.0 <4.2", would install "4.3.5")

× Migration failed: Incompatible peer dependencies found.

Peer dependency warnings when installing dependencies means that those dependencies might not work correctly together.

You can use the '--force' option to ignore incompatible peer dependencies and instead address these warnings later.
  See "C:\Users\DEFAUL~1.DES\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-13szno\angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

I'm not sure what the error is. I looked at the package.json file and I already have typescript 4.3.5.

Comment: Try running the `ng update` and include the `--force` argument. My experiences doing that have been good.

Comment: @R.Richards I was thinking that but read elsewhere that was not the best course of action. I went ahead and tried anyway. There were a few issues afterwards but may not be related to using the --force flag. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try by adding `--force` parameter to the command and ignore the warnings.

```
ng update @angular/core@11 @angular/cli@11 --force
```

Comment: I would like to point out that although this command will indeed update all libraries it might break the project dependencies, the --force key is a little bit dangerous, so I would advice against using it

Answer (score 0):

The ideal approach would be to resolve dependencies first and then use the migration command again. In some cases `yarn install` helps figuring out dependencies more clearly.